# NullPointerException while doing setContentView

Tags: android, view, android-mapview

This is the class that I have and give me the error:

```
public class ShowCarMapChild extends MapActivity {


private MapView mapView;
private Car car;
private String tag;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Log.d("hemendik pasetan da?", "bai!!");
    setContentView(R.layout.car_map_view);
}

public void setCar(Car car){
    this.car = car;
}

public void setTag (String tag){
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getTag (){
    return tag;
}

public View getMapView(Context context){
    Log.d("getMapView", "pass");
    setContentView(R.layout.car_map_view);
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_map_view, null);
    setMap(view,context);
    return view;
}




public void setMap(View view, Context context){
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapShowCarLocation);
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.animateTo(car.getLocation());
    mc.setZoom(15);
    PinpointItem point = new PinpointItem(car.getLocation(), car, context);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinpoint);
    CustomPinpointOverlay overlay = new CustomPinpointOverlay(d);
    overlay.insertPinpoint(point);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

The layout: car_map_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="150dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapShowCarLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0UFOPeLgKxoW8VGjdzV5QN6N53N7733i1kTFI3g"
        android:enabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error as I said in the title is while I do setContentView. I have to say also that I am trying to use this class to put as child in a expandable list. If the rest of the code is needed also just let me know.

Here is from where I call to the method getMapView(). Is from the BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
 public class ShowCarExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

 ....

 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (view == null){
        if (groupPosition == 0){
            Log.d("getChildView", "pass");
            ShowCarMapChild mapChild = (ShowCarMapChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            view = mapChild.getMapView(context);
            //LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //ShowCarMapChild mapChild = (ShowCarMapChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            //view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_map_view, null);
            //MapView mv = mapChild.getMap(view, context);
            //mv.setTag(mapChild.getTag());

        }else{
            Log.d("getChildView", "pass from else");
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ShowCarExpandChild child = (ShowCarExpandChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_child, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
            tv.setText(child.getName());
            tv.setTag(child.getTag());
        }           
    }
    return view;
}

  .....
```

Comment: It must be an error in your layout. Please can you post your layout content here so that we can help you?

Comment: There you have it! If you need something more just ask for it

Comment: Ok. Where did you call getMapView(...) method and why? I you need it in the same activity then you don't need any more to inflate it. Just call findbyId

Comment: I put also the method that calls to this one... I make inflate because it gives a view and I need to return a view. Anyway the problem comes before the inflate so this is not the problem.

Comment: There is any problem in your layout. Try to remove all other code and run only oncreate() it will work. I just copy and paste in my code and everything is ok.  Remember that you have 2 setcontentview(...) methods in your code

Comment: It is not working for me... I try to put everything in onCreate but it is still not working. Did you put the map in a expandable list as well? Because I think that this is also the problem that I have.

Comment: If you want you can send me the complet project so that i can dig in it. festus@tamakloe.de

Comment: hey there, did you solve it??